# Removing objects by Id

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to remove my 3DObject made with three.js by Id and it doesnt work but by Name it works. Am i doing something wrong?

```
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("objectname")); //works
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectById(objectID)); //doesn't work
```

Comment: Is it a valid ID that you're passing in?

Comment: Also according to the documentation .`getObjectById` accepts an integer as its parameter, Make sure thats the case.

Comment: i made sure i passed a correct id (with console.log).
i passed 72 as ID

Comment: Does the console log any errors ?

Comment: no it doesnt.. everything works fine but when i replace the functions, it doesnt work anymore.. it has to be the wrong Id..
I get my Id trough a raycast.. this has to be wrong, but i dont know why: intersects[0].object.id

Comment: So if you `console.log` byId version do you get anything?

Comment: yep, i get my object.

Comment: this is my code:
console.log(intersects[0].object.id) //output is 72
console.log("objekt: "+scene.getObjectById(intersects[0].object.id)); //output is object array with length 2 (i dont know why 2)
      scene.remove(scene.getObjectById(intersects[0].object.id)); //doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

`scene.remove()` only works if the object is a direct child of `scene`. Try to use this code instead:

```js
var object = scene.getObjectById( objectID )
var parent = object.parent;
parent.remove( object );
```

`three.js R109`

Answer (score 0):

I have half way of my answer. I know why it doesnt work but i have no solution.

The Raycast doesnt give the correct object.id back. intersects[0].object.id is 72 but when i create the object and log the id it is 21. Also the scene.object.name is BotSkinned (because i coded object.name = "BotSkinned"), but the Raycast says: intersects[0].object.name is "Bot_Skinned_0".
Somehow i want to link my Raycastobject to my coded object and im not sure how.. because i want to create multiple objects of 1 name i have to use the ID.